# using Google Heat Map API Service in ASP.net C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am new in Asp.Net Web development.

How to integrate Google Heat Maps into Asp.Net(C#) web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [GHeat for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88956/GHeat-NET) project. I used it in my last project that required Heat Map integration in C#.

If you're just wanting to use JS since it's for ASP.NET you just use [Googles API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap)

Comment: Hello Ryan.......Thanks for the reply. Does Google Heat Maps requires any paid subscription or we can use it freely??

Comment: @MSWebDev it's free to use.

Comment: Thanks Ryan.........the links suggested by you as per "GHeat for .NET" helped me......I just did bit of conversion of vb.net code to c# & it worked.......Thanks.